# sed - insert a "_" between [a-z][a-z][A-Z][a-z] >>> [a-z][a-z]_[A-Z][a-z]

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have filenames and made a failure in my sed script so I get:

```
"this_is_the_videoIphone.mp4"
"this_is_my_videoNikon.mp4"
"this_is_the_pictureIphone.mp4"
"this_VideoIphone.flv" ... and so on
```

I want a "_" between that.

a rule could be like this: (one or more [a-z]) followed by ([A-Z] followed by one or more [a-z])

I tried much but nothing works...

```
filename="$(echo $filename | sed -e 's/\(^.*[a-z]\)\([A-Z][a-z].*$\)/\1_\2/g')"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: what's with all the literal parentheses `\(`  should they be unescaped `(`?

Comment: @sweaver2112 No, the have to be escaped in BRE (basic regular expressions) for capture groups.

Comment: wrt `I want a "_" between that.` - you want a "_" between what? Between each line of output? [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input so we aren't guessing.

Comment: `echo this_is_my_videoNikon.mp4 | sed -e 's/\(^.*[a-z]\)\([A-Z][a-z].*$\)/\1_\2/g'` gives `this_is_my_video_Nikon.mp4`, so if you got what you're looking for, your `sed` should work? Though with the pattern anchored to the start and end of the line, I don't think it's going to match more than one once each line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/([a-z][a-z])([A-Z][a-z])/\1_\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B[[:upper:]]\B/_&/g' file
```

This inserts a `_` preceeding any uppercase character within a word.

N.B. This does not conform to your specification in that it would insert a `_` between two consecutive uppercase characters. Nor would it insert said character if the last character of the word was uppercase.